# Eventbrite Batch Endpoint - You passed a request body that was not in JSON format

Tags: php, json, eventbrite, php-curl

My JSON is below which validates fine (numbers are dummy numbers!). This string is assigned to the variable `$payload`.

```
[{
    "method": "GET",
    "relative_url": "series/4/events/?expand=ticket_classes"
}, {
    "method": "GET",
    "relative_url": "series/5/events/?expand=ticket_classes"
}, {
    "method": "GET",
    "relative_url": "series/6/events/?expand=ticket_classes"
}, {
    "method": "GET",
    "relative_url": "series/7/events/?expand=ticket_classes"
}, {
    "method": "GET",
    "relative_url": "series/8/events/?expand=ticket_classes"
}, {
    "method": "GET",
    "relative_url": "series/9/events/?expand=ticket_classes"
}]
```

My PHP is as follows:

```
    $url = "https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/batch/?token=".$token;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$payload);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
        'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($payload))                                                                       
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    $body = \curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $json = \json_decode($body,true);
    echo $body;
```

The echo is spitting out:

```
{"status_code": 400, "error_description": "You passed a request body that was not in JSON format.", "error": "INVALID_BODY"}
```

Everything seems fine - an I missing something obvious?

When I pass the data through the https://www.eventbriteapi.com site, for each one I get a body response that just has the pagination details and no event details...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Edit HTTPClient.php

Replace this:

```
   $options = array(
        'http'=>array(
            'method'=>$httpMethod,
            'header'=>"content-type: application/json\r\n",
            'content'=>$data,
            'ignore_errors'=>true
        )
    );
```

With this:

```
    $options = array(
        'http'=>array(
            'method'=>$httpMethod,
            'header'=>"content-type: application/json\r\n",
            'ignore_errors'=>true
        )
    );

    if ($httpMethod == 'POST') {
        $options['http']['content'] = $data;
    }
```

Reference: https://github.com/eventbrite/eventbrite-sdk-php/issues/7#issuecomment-308537756

Answer (score 0):

Below is what has worked for me. Both the Insomnia / Postman instructions, as well as a simple PHP cURL.

**Endpoint**: https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/batch/
**Method**: Post
**Header**: Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
**Auth**: Bearer Token
Pass the body as Form URL Encoded
**Name**: Batch 
**Value:**

```
[    {"method":"GET", "relative_url":"events/EVENT_ID/attendees?page=1"},    {"method":"GET", "relative_url":"events/EVENT_ID_HERE/attendees?page=2"},   {"method":"GET", "relative_url":"events/EVENT_ID_HERE/attendees?page=3"},   {"method":"GET", "relative_url":"events/EVENT_ID_HERE/attendees?page=3"}  ]
```

Simple PHP cURL

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/batch/",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "batch=%5B%20%09%20%7B%22method%22%3A%22GET%22%2C%20%22relative_url%22%3A%22events%2FEVENT_ID_HERE%2Fattendees%3Fpage%3D1%22%7D%2C%20%09%20%7B%22method%22%3A%22GET%22%2C%20%22relative_url%22%3A%22events%2FEVENT_ID_HERE%2Fattendees%3Fpage%3D2%22%7D%2C%20%09%20%7B%22method%22%3A%22GET%22%2C%20%22relative_url%22%3A%22events%2FEVENT_ID_HERE%2Fattendees%3Fpage%3D3%22%7D%2C%20%09%20%7B%22method%22%3A%22GET%22%2C%20%22relative_url%22%3A%22events%2FEVENT_ID_HERE%2Fattendees%3Fpage%3D3%22%7D%20%20%5D&=",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "authorization: Bearer TOKEN GOES HERE",
    "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a pretty old question. However, for anyone else who runs into this issue. When using "Content-Type: application/json" you will want to pass a double encoded JSON object.

```
{"batch": "[{
    \"method\": \"GET\",
    \"relative_url\": \"series/4/events/?expand=ticket_classes\"
}, {
    \"method\": \"GET\",
    \"relative_url\": \"series/5/events/?expand=ticket_classes\"
}, {
    \"method\": \"GET\",
    \"relative_url\": \"series/6/events/?expand=ticket_classes\"
}, {
    \"method\": \"GET\",
    \"relative_url\": \"series/7/events/?expand=ticket_classes\"
}, {
    \"method\": \"GET\",
    \"relative_url\": \"series/8/events/?expand=ticket_classes\"
}, {
    \"method\": \"GET\",
    \"relative_url\": \"series/9/events/?expand=ticket_classes\"
}]"
}
```

This is another option and this should fix the issue.